# subtracting unmatching column from two dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, numpy-ndarray

I have two dataframes(missingData and bias) and one Series(missingDateUnique).

```py
missingDateUnique = pd.Series({0: 2459650, 9: 2459654})

missingDate = pd.DataFrame({0: [2459650, 2459650,2459650,2459654,2459654,2459654], 1: [10, 10,10,14,14,14]},index=[0,1,2,9,10,11])

bias = pd.DataFrame({0: [2459651, 2459652,2459653,2459655,2459656,2459658,2459659], 1: [11, 12,13,15,16,18,19]})
```

As missingDateUnique values are not in bias dataFrame. I have to check for i+1 in bias dataframe and subtract the 1's column value with missingDate's value.

I was doing it like this

```py
for i in missingDateUnique:
   if i+1 in bias[0].values:
       missingDate[1] = missingDate[1].sub(missingDate[0].map(bias.set_index(0)[1]),fill_value=0)
```

The result should be like---

In missingDate's 1st row instead of 10 it should be 11-10=1

Full output-----

```
2459650     1
2459650     1
2459650     1
2459654     1
2459654     1
2459654     1
```

For example 2459654 in `missingDate` i have to check for 2459655 and 2459653 both in `bias` and subtract with any one from that. If both 2459655 and 2459653 are not present then I have to check for 2459656 and 2459652 and so on

Comment: Please provide the full expected output.

Comment: updated sir..check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract 1 from `bias` column `0` and map it to `missingDate` column `0`

```py
missingDate[2] = missingDate[0].map(bias.assign(key=bias[0]-1).set_index('key')[1]) - missingDate[1]
```

```
print(missingDate)

          0   1  2
0   2459650  10  1
1   2459650  10  1
2   2459650  10  1
9   2459654  14  1
10  2459654  14  1
11  2459654  14  1
```

Comment: sir don't i need to use the missingDateUnique variable? I have to check i+1 in bias if it is not available then i need to check for i-1

Comment: @PritamDas You don't need `missingDateUnique`. For `i+1` and `i-1` could you give an example?

Comment: sir for 2459654 in ``` missingDate``` i have to check for  2459655 and 2459653 both in bias and subtract with any one from that. If both 2459655 and 2459653 are not present then I have to check for 2459656 and 2459652 and so on

Comment: @PritamDas You'd better include this information in your post...

Comment: updated the post sir

Comment: @PritamDas Don't have good idea on this situation, you could unaccepted this answer.

Comment: it solves my base case sir. I just need to apply this logic in loop by some way

Comment: @PritamDas It's not easy because it's difficult to know how many the `n` is in `i+n` or `i-n`. It will be easy if you just want the nearest in which you can use `merge_asof.`

Comment: yes sir..i got that